# Passing data that can be used by an AWS ALB filter when initialising socket.io using web socket transport

Tags: socket.io, aws-application-load-balancer

We have an AWS Application Load Balancer which forwards to an auto-scaling group of EC2 instances running a node.js socket.io installation.

The socket.io installation uses the @socket.io/cluster-adapter package to enable multi-processor support.

I've chosen websocket transport to avoid needing a sticky session because the @socket.io/sticky doesn't support HTTPS.

However, I need to use a "rule" on the load balancer HTTPS listener to route incoming requests to different auto-scaling groups because we have one auto-scaling group per project.  Socket.io has an extraHeaders initialisation property, but that doesn't work with websockets, as it relies on the initial long polling handshake.

So it's a catch-22 as far as I can see.

Is there any way to pass a `projectId` to the load balancer as socket.io initialises if I am only using the websockets transport, please?

Thank you.